# Karate - issue when while running scenario in the loop

Tags: karate

I want to run a scenario in the loop and following the data-driven approach for the same but unable to read the key's value when passing to the API path. This works well if I use it in the API request payload -

Eg.

i have arraylist = `[ {name: "mysql_datasource_id"} ]`

I am calling the `schema.feature` file's scenario tagged with `@try` tag -

```
* def get_schemas = read('schema.feature@try')
* def result = call get_schemas arraylist
```

The scenario which is in `schema.feature` with `@try` tag -

```
Given url datasource_host + '/' + '#(name)' + '/schemas'
And request { name : '#(name)'}
When method post
Then status 200
```

for the above scenario `name` which is in the request gets replaced with `mysql_datasource_id` but the `name` which is in the path of the API remain as `'#(name)'`

PFA Screenshot of the output -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It works when I pass the normal `name` to the API path instead of the `'#(name)'`